# Collect values from an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, collect

I have a data structure in the following format:

```
data_hash = [
    { price: 1, count: 3 },
    { price: 2, count: 3 },
    { price: 3, count: 3 }
  ]
```

Is there an efficient way to get the values of `:price` as an array like `[1,2,3]`?

Comment: The example you give is not valid ruby syntax. (Without a valid example we can't help you). Also, it would helpful if you show us what you've already tried.

Comment: We need to see your attempt at solving this problem. Without your code it looks like you're just asking someone to write code for you, which is a great way to get your question closed. Otherwise, we can simply say, "Yes, there is an efficient way to get the values" and leave it to you to figure it out. Which would you prefer?

Comment: Probably the question should swap `{ }` and `[ ]` brackets (making it an array of hashes). I just tried for 5 mins to find an existing question (I am really convinced this is a duplicate), but I think SO has buried the answers under more complex examples.

Comment: Use data_hash.pluck(:price) now, for the love of god

Comment: @Rambatino pluck is a rails method. This is a general ruby question.

Comment: @ParkerKemp old me was naïve, you are correct, there is no rails reference in here and that functionality does come from rails

Answer (score 134):

First, if you are using ruby < 1.9:

```
array = [
    {:price => 1, :count => 3},
    {:price => 2, :count => 3},
    {:price => 3, :count => 3}
]
```

Then to get what you need:

```
array.map{|x| x[:price]}
```

Comment: The updated syntax for the "hash" is correct, but at that point `data_hash` is a misnomer. The OP should use `data_hashes` or `data_array`, either of which would be better.

Comment: Oops, you are right. Corrected.

Answer (score 4):

There is a closed question that redirects here asking about handing `map` a Symbol to derive a key. This can be done using an Enumerable as a middle-man:

```rb
array = [
    {:price => 1, :count => 3},
    {:price => 2, :count => 3},
    {:price => 3, :count => 3}
]

array.each.with_object(:price).map(&:[])

#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Beyond being slightly more verbose and more difficult to understand, it also slower.

```rb
Benchmark.bm do |b| 
  b.report { 10000.times { array.map{|x| x[:price] } } }
  b.report { 10000.times { array.each.with_object(:price).map(&:[]) } }
end

#       user     system      total        real
#   0.004816   0.000005   0.004821 (  0.004816)
#   0.015723   0.000606   0.016329 (  0.016334)
```

Answer (score 2):

If using Rails, you may also use the following solution, because Rails patches the class `Enumerable`:

```rb
array = [
    {:price => 1, :count => 3},
    {:price => 2, :count => 3},
    {:price => 3, :count => 3}
]

array.pluck(:price)

#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Reference: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-pluck

Unfortunately, the implementation is pure ruby, so I wouldn't expect an increase in speed.